# Question about deploying a microservices app on Kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes, microservices, client-side

I am working on an application that will be deployed on EKS. In its first form it will have three micro-services.

- VueJS Front-end
- Python Back-end server
- ML Inference Server

Only the Front-end will be exposed to the outside of the cluster via load balancing. The Python backend will act as an intermediary with the Inference Server and other services that will be added in the future.

My question is that if the Vue Front-end is in the cluster, it can interact with the back-end trough clusterIP. But when a user connect to the front end via a browser, the app is in the browser (client-side). So will the request that goes from Vue to the backend will work using the clusterIP or do I need to expose the backend.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You need to expose the backend services with an ingress. In order for the ingress object to work correctly an ingress controller needs to be installed and configured in the cluster.

More information in: https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/ingress-controllers/